# Align the forest from left to right

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

Recently, I applied [`cfr`'s code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207014/44227) to what I wanted (see below).
[image]

But I want to arrange this diagram from left to right in order to put into my book, that is, put the topmost box at the left side of page and stack `child`s upside down, how could I do it?

The following is the Modified code.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  font=\sffamily,
  line width=1pt,
  draw=linecol,
  drop shadow,
  fit=rectangle,
  edge={thick, color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
  where level=0{%
    l sep+=5pt,
    calign=child,
    calign child=2,
    inner color=PaleGreen1!80,
    outer color=PaleGreen1,
    align=center,
    my rounded corners,
    for descendants={%
      calign=first,
    },
  }{%
    where level=1{%
      inner color=Green2!80,
      outer color=Green2,
      my rounded corners,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=west, 
      tier=three ways,
      for descendants={%
        child anchor=west, 
        parent anchor=west,
        align=left,
        anchor=west,
        inner color=MistyRose1!80,
        outer color=MistyRose1,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
          (!to tier=three ways.parent anchor) |-
          (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
    }{}%
  },
  }
  [Nonlinear Stochastic Systems
[Robust Control and Filtering
  [Chapter 2\\Robust Stabilization
    [Chapter 3\\ Robust ${H}_\infty$ Control
      [Chapter 4\\ ${H}_\infty$ Filtering and Control[Chapter 6\\ Robust Filtering
      ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
[Applications to Special Systems
[Chapter 5\\Gene Regulatory Networks
    [Chapter 7\\ Networked Control Systems
      [Chapter 8\\ Complex Networks]
    ]
  ]]
[Gain-Scheduled Method
  [Chapter 9\\  Probability-Dependent Gain-Scheduled Control
    [Chapter 10\\ Probability-Dependent Gain-Scheduled Filtering
      [Chapter 11\\Probability-Dependent ${H}_\infty$ Synchronization Control ]
    ]
  ]
]
[Razumikhin Theory
  [Chapter 12\\ ${H}_\infty$ Analysis
    ]
   ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [the answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244742/4778) answers your problems? See the second solution in the answer for the `forest` package.

Comment: I would, but it's really the same answer. Do like this: Grab my code in that answer, then simply replace the content with yours. You can fix the textwidth in the `tnode` style (the pink one) so that the nodes are wider, but really, that's it. :D

Comment: Thank you, I have adapt your code, but I also encounter a problem, maybe this one can have your attention http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254284/44227