# Draw a box containing the grandchild and add text at the bottom of box

Tags: boxes, forest

I want to draw a minimal box which contains all the `grandchild`s (pink boxes), [image] and move the text of deep green box to the bottom of the new box.  How could I do it?

codes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    basic1/.style  = {draw,  drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,                    fill=green!30},
    onode/.style = {basic, thin, rounded corners=2pt, align=center, fill=green!60,text width=3cm,},
    tnode/.style = {basic1, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60},
    edge from parent/.style={draw=black, edge from parent fork right}
}
%
\begin{document}
\title{Structure of Book}
\begin{forest} for tree={anchor=base west,
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0pt) |- (.child anchor)
         \forestoption{edge label};}
}
[Nonlinear Stochastic Systems, root
       [{Applications to Complex Systems, NCSs, GRNs}, onode
       [Chapter 8\\ Complex Networks, tnode]
        [Chapter 7\\ Networked Control Systems, tnode] 
        [Chapter 5\\Gene Regulatory Networks, tnode] ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to make to deep green box a child of the main root? Sorry but your question is unclear for me...

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @Alenanno has solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

Here's the new version using two boxes. I changed the space between the nodes to make it possible to have multiple dashed boxes.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,fit,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    basic1/.style  = {draw,  drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,                    fill=green!30},
    onode/.style = {basic, thin, rounded corners=2pt, align=center, fill=green!60,text width=3cm,},
    tnode/.style = {basic1, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60},
    edge from parent/.style={draw=black, edge from parent fork right}
}
%
\begin{document}
\title{Structure of Book}
\begin{forest} for tree={anchor=base west,
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,l sep+=1em,s sep=5mm,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) -- +(1em,0pt) |- (.child anchor)
         \forestoption{edge label};}
}
[Nonlinear Stochastic Systems, root
       [Chapter 8\\ Complex Networks, tnode, name=eight]
        [Chapter 7\\ Networked Control Systems, tnode, name=seven] 
        [Chapter 5\\Gene Regulatory Networks, tnode, name=five]
        [Chapter 11\\randomly varying nonlinearities, tnode, name=eleven]
        [Chapter 6 \, 10\\missing measurement, tnode] 
        [Chapter 9\\randomly occurring nonlinearities, tnode, name=nine] ] ] 
%
\node [draw, dashed, black!40, inner sep=.4em, fit={(eight) (five) (seven)}, label={[align=left]0:Applications to\\Complex Systems,\\NCSs, GRNs}] {};
\node [draw, dashed, black!40, inner sep=.4em, fit={(eleven) (nine)}, label={[align=left]0:Analysis of\\something complex\\more text}] {};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alenanno I understand why I can't work it out it seems the `\node` line can only be placed at the bottom of the codes.

Comment: @WangyanLi Well, if you're referencing nodes then the referenced nodes must appear *before*. If you say `place this node right of n1`, but n1 appears afterwards, then Latex will say "I don't know this node you're referring to".

Comment: Yes, I understand. I notice that the `\node[]{};` was placed at the bottom of the code instead of, for example, `chapter 5` and `chapter 11` which is my   way to do it ending with errors.

Comment: @WangyanLi I don't think you can do that with `forest`, but even if you could, I prefer to organise the code where everything similar appears grouped in the same place so that it's easier to find them and also it's less prone to errors.

Comment: You *can* specify them within the tree... ;).

Comment: Thanks, but, any example will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This responds to queries in the comments on [Alenanno's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254630/).

If you want something like this:

[image: groups]

It is not necessary to name the nodes explicitly if we use relative node names and specify the additional `\node` commands within the tree itself. This can be done using the `tikz` key or the `afterthought` key. In the following, I use the former. I've also pruned the unnecessary style `onode` (which originally stood for 'orange node', by the way). I've also tidied up a bit and improved the spacing which was a bit squashed in the version I posted earlier.

`fitbox` specifies the style used to draw the dashed boxes. I've made all nodes have rounded corners as it looked odd to me to have a mixture but you can obviously adapt this.

`fitting` is a style which takes one argument. This specifies the nodes to be included in the dashed box. You can either use explicitly named nodes e.g. `(nine)` and name a node `name=nine` or use relative node names as I have here. `(!n)` is the next sibling, `(!nn)` is the next sibling's sibling and so on.

This makes the code a bit cleaner and easier to read.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,fit}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow},
    basic1/.style = {draw,  drop shadow, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
    tnode/.style = {basic1, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, rounded corners=2pt},
    fitbox/.style = {draw, gray, dashed, inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=7.5pt, rounded corners=2pt},
}
\forestset{
  fitting/.style={
    tikz={\node [fitbox, fit=#1] {};},
    no edge,
    inner ysep=0pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\title{Structure of Book}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    anchor=base west,
    grow=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    l sep+=1em,
    align=left,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={->, >={latex}},
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]  (!u.parent anchor) -- +(1em,0pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root
    [{Applications to\\Complex Systems,\\NCSs, GRNs}, fitting={(!nnn) (!n) (!nn)}]
    [Chapter 8\\ Complex Networks, tnode]
    [Chapter 7\\ Networked Control Systems, tnode]
    [Chapter 5\\Gene Regulatory Networks, tnode]
    [{Analysis and Synthesis\\for Systems with\\Incomplete Information},  fitting={(!n) (!nn) (!nnn)}]
    [Chapter 11\\randomly varying nonlinearities, tnode]
    [{Chapter 6, 10\\something},tnode]
    [{Chapter 9\\randomly occurring somethings},tnode]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just omit `()` in the argument to `fit` if you don't want the title in the dashed box.

Comment: Your solution is more clever, I'm enjoying it.  Thanks indeed.

Comment: I have noticed some changes in your codes, but I can't understand it well, for example, `fit=() (*) (*) (*)` has modified to `fitting={(!nnn) (!n) (!nn)}`, could you explain it a bit to me or give me some hints which I can refer to.

Comment: @WangyanLi `fitting` is just a style I added for convenience, whereas `fit` is the underlying style provided by the `fit` library. So, `fitting` is just like `fit` except that it also adds `no edge, inner ysep=0pt` and applies the `fitbox` style. The node names I've used are *relative* node names. `(!n)` is the next sibling, `(!nn)` is the next sibling's sibling and so on. It just means I don't have to name the nodes and that the code will adapt automatically if I insert an additional sibling. Does that help?

Comment: @WangyanLi Oh, and `()` refers to the current node, so I omitted it because I realised you didn't want the titles within the dashed boxes.

Comment: Yes, it's genius, I don't notice you have added a long explanation words in your answer, forgive me.